# why do keras-rl examples always choose linear activation in the output layer?

Tags: keras, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm a complete newbie to Reinforcement Learning. And I have a question about the choice of the activation function of the output layer for the keras-rl agents. In all the examples provided by keras-rl (https://github.com/matthiasplappert/keras-rl/tree/master/examples) choose linear activation function in the output layer. Why is this? What effect would we expect if I go with different activation function? For example, if I work with an OpenAI environment with a discrete action space of 5, should I also consider using softmax in the output layer for an agent?
Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some of the agents in keras-rl `linear` activation function is used, even though the agents are working with discrete action spaces (for example, dqn, ddqn). But, for example, CEM uses `softmax` activation function for discrete action spaces (which is what one would expect).

The reason behind `linear` activation function for dqn and ddqn is its exploration policy, which is a part of the agent. If we consider the class of exploration policy used for both of them as an example and a method `select_action`, we will see the following:

```
class BoltzmannQPolicy(Policy):
def __init__(self, tau=1., clip=(-500., 500.)):
    super(BoltzmannQPolicy, self).__init__()
    self.tau = tau
    self.clip = clip

def select_action(self, q_values):
    assert q_values.ndim == 1
    q_values = q_values.astype('float64')
    nb_actions = q_values.shape[0]

    exp_values = np.exp(np.clip(q_values / self.tau, self.clip[0], self.clip[1]))
    probs = exp_values / np.sum(exp_values)
    action = np.random.choice(range(nb_actions), p=probs)
    return action
```

In decision-making process for every action, output of `linear` activation function of the last `dense` layer is transformed according to Boltzmann exploration policy to range [0,1], and the decision on a specific action is made according to Boltzmann exploration. That's why `softmax` is not used in an output layer.

You can read more about different exploration strategies and their comparison here:
https://medium.com/emergent-future/simple-reinforcement-learning-with-tensorflow-part-7-action-selection-strategies-for-exploration-d3a97b7cceaf

Comment: Thanks much for this great explanation. It helps very much!